# Стоит ли сохранять весь сайт в localStorage, чтоб уменьшить потребление интернета?

Tags: javascript, html, css, localstorage

Внезапно посетила такая интересная мысль:

А что, если сохранять весь статический код сайта (JS, CSS, HTML и т.д.) в localStorage?
Правда, пока не знаю, насколько "законным" является такой подход.

Comment: Браузеры сами кешируют статику очень задолго до появления local storage, а может и до появления js самого по себе - я не достаточно старый чтобы помнить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS и JS сами кэшируются браузером, и что-то специального для этого делать не надо.

HTML файлы тоже могут кэшироваться но это зависит от настроек сайта (наличие специальных заголовков, инструкций для кэширования у страницы). 90% это правильно настроить это кэширование.

Картинки тоже сами кэшируются браузером.

Думаю элементы html легко можно кэшировать в localStorage, если это необходимо, и обычное браузерное кэширование не подходит.

Можно почитать про [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API), технологии которая делается специально для кэширования, правда она ещё находится на стадии разработки.

Comment: элементы html кэшировать нельзя. так как они в общем случае не сериализуются. возможно имелась ввиду html разметка?

Comment: @Grundy можно взять outerHTML и как строчку сохранить. или если они пришли данными через ajax запрос сохранить сам JSON или даже HTML строку. Я не имел ввиду элементы как объекты DOM, просто в общем понимании слова элемент.